# How to use the explicit formula for divergence in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator

I'm not sure how to use correctly
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2 F^r) + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \partial_\theta (\sin \theta F^\theta) + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \partial_\phi F^\phi$$

For exemple, I have $\vec{F}$ = $r^3\phi sin(\theta)(\hat{u_r} + \hat{u_\phi} + \hat{u_\theta})$

Do I just replace $F^r$ with $r^3$ and so on then find the derivative?

Is this just a plug and go formula?

Comment: Here, $F^r=F^{\phi}=F^{\theta}=r^3\phi\sin\theta$. Be sure to substitute the correct thing.

Comment: I though $F^r$ was only the $\hat{U}_r$ component of $\vec{F}$

Comment: right. What does that mean? It means $F^r$ is equal to whatever appears infront of $\hat{u}_r$. In this case it is $r^3\phi\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you simply take partial derivative as stated in the formula. In this case,

$\vec F = r^3 \phi \sin \theta \ (\hat{u_r} + \hat{u_\phi} + \hat{u_\theta}) = r^3 \phi \sin \theta \ \hat{u_r} + r^3 \phi \sin \theta \ \hat{u_\phi} + r^3 \phi \sin \theta \ \hat{u_\theta}$

Now simply take derivative for each component.

$\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r (r^2 F^r) = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r (r^5 \phi \sin \theta) = 5r^2 \phi \sin\theta$

$\frac{1}{r \sin\theta}\partial_{\phi} (F^{\phi}) = \frac{1}{r \sin\theta}\partial_{\phi} (r^3 \phi \sin\theta) = ?$

$\frac{1}{r \sin\theta}\partial_{\theta} (\sin \theta F^{\theta}) = \frac{1}{r \sin\theta}\partial_{\theta} (r^3 \phi \sin^2 \theta) = ?$

Comment: Alright, thanks. 

And If $$\vec{F} = \frac{1}{4\pi \cdot r^3}(2cos(\theta)\hat{U}_r + sin(\theta)\hat{U}_\theta) + 0\hat{U}_\phi$$ then 

$$\frac{1}{r sin \theta}(\partial \theta(sin \theta \cdot 0) - \partial \phi(\frac{sin \theta}{4\pi r^3}))\hat{r}$$

Comment: But that is for $\hat r$ component of the _curl_ ($\nabla \times \vec F$) and not divergence ($\nabla \cdot \vec F$). Are you to find curl of this vector field or divergence?